# Differentiating between different login session in asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, session

How can i differentiate between different login sessions ? When a user logs in, his credentials(username/password) are stored in session and other user logs in his credentials are stored in session but the problem is the previous user's shopping cart is being retained, how can i delete the shopping cart if a different user logs in ? How can i differentiate between 2 different sessions ??

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: What are you doing when user logs out?

Comment: for example the user doesn't log out and other user logs in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During login process you can do `Session.Clear()` and then put initial values

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that a login control should not be visible when someone is currently autheticated, only a logout link. Then, on logout:

```
Session.Clear();
```